# How to get pixel length of a Button text string in QML?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I need to know Button text length in pixels.
How to do that ?

Comment: This question must be shared with StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: 160
    height: 160

    Button {
        id: my_button
        Text {
            id: my_text
            anchors {centerIn: parent }
            text: my_button.width + " x " + my_button.height
        }
        Component.onCompleted: console.log(my_text.width)
    }
}
```

The default text property of a button is just a string and will inherit the style applied on the Button component.

To get access to the string length in pixel, use instead a dedicated Text element inside your button so that you can access its pixel width like this: `my_text.width`.

Running the above code with qmlscene logs `41.953125` on the standard output for the string "80 x 40"